# Appium with Genymotion (Vbox) "2 devices found, 0 emulators connected" - Android

Tags: python, appium, genymotion

I'm trying to run an Android test via Appium using Genymotion vbox emulator.

The emulator is up and when checking "adb devices -l" i get the correct IP for both devices connected:

"List of devices attached
192.168.56.102:5555     device
192.168.56.101:5555     device"

When i'm running the script, the appium runs the following log over and over again:

> info: [debug] Trying to find Android1 emulator
>   info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\omria\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   error: Unable to start Emulator: PANIC: HOME is defined but could not find Android1.ini file in $HOME.android\avd
>   (Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME.android\avd and $HOME.android\avd)
>
> info: [debug] 2 device(s) connected
>   info: [debug] 0 emulator(s) connected
>   info: [debug] Trying to find Android1 emulator
>   info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\omria\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   info: [debug] 2 device(s) connected
>   info: [debug] 0 emulator(s) connected
>   info: [debug] Trying to find Android1 emulator
>   info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\omria\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   info: [debug] 2 device(s) connected
>   info: [debug] 0 emulator(s) connected
>   info: [debug] Trying to find Android1 emulator
>   info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\omria\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   info: [debug] 2 device(s) connected
>   info: [debug] 0 emulator(s) connected

This doesn't stop until i kill  the server.

Does anyone have any idea regarding this problem? tried ~100 google results and none solved my problem.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

The code:

```
import os
from appium import webdriver

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.4.45'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = '192.168.56.101:5555'
desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'XXX'
desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'XXX'

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4725/wd/hub', desired_caps)


driver.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.Button")[0].click()
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.EditText")[0].send_keys("7725627513")
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.EditText")[1].send_keys("pass1234")
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.Button")[1].click()
```

My Appium settings:

[Appium settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWwZb.png)

Comment: Whats your code to instantiate the driver? Please add the same along with the capabilities used by you in the question.

Comment: I just edited the question with the info.